# How to find quantity in a certain attribute in a related polygon in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I have two polygons as below:

1. Polygon1 is the physical boundaries;
2. Polygon2 is the building inside the polygon1;

The polygon2 has an attribute called "household quantity" which is the amount shown in the picture.

I want to figure out the household quantity of polygon2 inside polygon1.

Is there a quick way to do the job in ArcGIS because the data has millions of buildings?

Example:
Polygon1,the first boundary has 1+2+3=6 household totally;
Polygon1,the second boundary has 5+9=14 household totally;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) tool in ArcGIS.

[image]

Parameters:

1. TargetFeature = Polygon1
2. Join Features = Polygon2
3. Set Output Feature Class
4. Use Field map: Just use "Household Quantity" field and delete others.This method increases performance.
   Join Operation: Join_One_To_Many
5. Match Option: Use "Intersect" or "Completely Within".Maybe you want to use another methods based on the layers and your purpose.
6. Click Ok. The result feature class has all of the Polygon2 in the Polygon1.